# python 3 multiprocessing or multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

i have about 50 instances of class, which send SNMP-requests to different devices (one instance per device) every two minutes and save results in their self.variables. What should I use - multiprocessing or multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

You should use neither.  Instead, embrace I/O multiplexing.  You can easily handle 50 connections sending one message per 120 seconds in a single thread.

There are built-in facilities in Python 3 for this: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/selectors.html

Comment: if device is not responding (offline, etc) - single thread is getting frozen

Comment: @VladimirAkkerman: Not if you use I/O multiplexing.  You do not simply use blocking sockets and wait for frozen connections - you use `select()` or similar to only receive on sockets which are ready.  You can handle 50 connections very easily in a single thread.